# No handlers could be found for logger "mongo_connector.util"

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, py2neo

I always got the error below when I try to run mongo-connector with neo4j doc manager. I also tried with a config file as in https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/blob/master/config.json

Where is the problem?

```
mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:7474/db/data -d neo4j_doc_manager
No handlers could be found for logger "mongo_connector.util"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mongo-connector", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 85, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 1041, in main
    conf.parse_args()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/config.py", line 118, in parse_args
    option, dict((k, values.get(k)) for k in option.cli_names))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 824, in apply_doc_managers
    module = import_dm_by_name(dm['docManager'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 803, in import_dm_by_name
    module = __import__(full_name, fromlist=(name,))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/neo4j_doc_manager.py", line 16, in <module>
    from py2neo import Graph, authenticate
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/py2neo/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from py2neo.database import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/py2neo/database/__init__.py", line 65
    parameters = {k: v for k, v in parameters.items() if k not in presub_parameters}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Python 2.6. I'm not sure if that version is officially supported for this project. I would suggest upgrading to Python 2.7 or preferably 3.4 and trying to reproduce.